# Oracle Apex- Interactive Grid- Reset Button

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

In the Interactive Grid Toolbars of Oracle APEX, How can we make the reset button to show as icon only button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I found another way by adding the jsinitialization code in the attribute section of Interactive Grid as below

function(config) {
                  var $ = apex.jQuery,
                  toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar(),
                  lastToolbarGroup = toolbarData[toolbarData.length - 1],
                  createButton = {
                                    type: "BUTTON",
                                    icon: "a-Icon icon-ig-reset",
                                    iconOnly: true,
                                    action: "reset-report"
                                  };
                   lastToolbarGroup.controls.pop();
                   lastToolbarGroup.controls.push(createButton);
                   config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
                   config.initialSelection = false;
                   return config;
                 }
```

Comment: This way is better.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think I understood your question ... :) but...

I do not think there is a way to edit this feature of interactive grid. It is possible through javascript, but I think it is an unnecessary work.

```
$('button[data-action=reset-report] > span.a-Button-label').remove()
```

Or CSS

```
button[data-action=reset-report] > span.a-Button-label {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I thought that making the icon only button increase the effective utilization of toolbar space in lower resolutions

Comment: Ah yes, in this case it makes sense.